# How can I use small caps in the condition of abbreviation?

Tags: small-caps

I am making abbreviations part of my book. A sample is presented as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,openbib,draft]{book} 
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[total={5in, 8in}]{geometry} 
%% 備註   % 對表格的備注只能使用\footnote{text}
\usepackage[ruled]{bigfoot}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcounter{footalt}
\def\thefootalt{\fnsymbol{footalt}}
\MakeSortedPerPage{footalt}
\WithSuffix\def\footnotedefault'{\refstepcounter{footalt}
    \Footnotedefault{\thefootalt}}
\usepackage[hang]{footmisc} 


%% Abbreviation
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tocfill}{\cleaders\hbox{$\m@th \mkern\@dotsep mu . \mkern\@dotsep mu$}\hfill}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\abbrlabel}[1]{\makebox[3cm][l]{\textbf{#1}\ \tocfill}}
\newenvironment{abbreviations}{\begin{list}{}{\renewcommand{\makelabel}{\abbrlabel}%
            \setlength{\labelwidth}{3cm}\setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}%
            \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}}{\end{list}}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Abbreviations}

\begin{abbreviations}
    \item[PV\textsc{d}] The embedded word of {\it Pramāṇavārttika} in De
    \item[PVe\textsc{m}] The embedded word of {\it Pramāṇavārttika} in M
    \item[PVe\textsc{m}1] The embedded word of {\it Pramāṇavārttika} in M1
\end{abbreviations}

The following is the second part:

[PV\textsc{d}] The embedded word of {\it Pramāṇavārttika} in De

[PVe\textsc{m}] The embedded word of {\it Pramāṇavārttika} in M

[PVe\textsc{m}1] The embedded word of {\it Pramāṇavārttika} in M1

\end{document}
```

[image]

However `\textsc{xxx}` command does not function (like those shown in second part) under abbreviation condition.  What can I do for this?

Comment: Please make your code snippet compilable ... Answers can be dependent of used document class etc.

Comment: Please help us help you and add a minimal working example (MWE) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Note that `\it` has been obsolete in LaTeX for decades and ought not be used. `\\ ` ought almost never be used outside special contexts such as `tabular` and `array`. To be fair, though, `abbreviations` might be defined as `tabular` in your document and `\item` might be redefined to print the name of a small antelope. In that case, it's obviously OK, though you should still avoid `\it`.

Comment: If you want everything in small-caps in the list, just add `\scshape` to the environment definition. `\it` will break this, of course. Also, use `url` to format URLs. If you really do want it all in small-caps, consider using italic small-caps by selecting a suitable font configuration.

Comment: @Cragfelt thanks. And I have amended the question as your request. Please give me some advice.

Comment: I am still waiting for the right answer to my question. Before that, I found that I can use subscript size to form the letter in order to achieve the effect.

Comment: Try `usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. The default fonts don't support bold smallcaps.